# Anular inicio de sesion automatico al registrar usuario en Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

tengo un problema que no puedo solucionar. Alguien sabe como hacer para que al registrar un nuevo usuario el sistema ni inicie sesion automáticamente con el nuevo usuario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas sobreescribir diferentes métodos de RegisterController

```
// Agrega estas referencias
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

...

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Comment: Jonathan Orta Gracias lo solucione con esto.